# Blender 2.8 sometime I can not open my blender file by OpenGL 3.3 Error

Tags: blend-files, opengl, saving

Sometimes I can not open my blender file.
I save the blender file and then I can not open it in next time.
But I can open other blender file.
graphic driver is latest ver
Blender file is broken ? I can not open backup file also [image]

Answer (score 1):

Graphics drivers sometimes crash. Try restarting the PC and closing all other graphics intensive applications before opening the file. You may also try using older version of the driver. Sometimes there are bugs in the driver updates even though it's rare and probably unlikely. It might be that the file is just corrupt. This might happen if your storage device is malfunctioning or for other reasons like overclocked CPU failing during writing the file. Try appending stuff from it to a new file.

Comment: appending suff from it to a new file and save. and I can open it again. Thank you !